# Only subviews added in viewDidLoad automatically resize

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I've created a custom subclass of UIViewController that acts like a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController. Let's call it a ToolbarNavController. It has a toolbar at the bottom with controls for the user to move to a different content view.

I have two content views aside from the ToolbarNavController's view. Both are loaded from a nib and have their own controllers. The app starts out showing one of them. A button in the toolbar allows the user to switch between them.

When I add these views as subviews of the ToolbarNavController's views in viewDidLoad, they are correctly resized to fill the area between the status bar and the toolbar without overlap/underlap.

But when I try to lazy load the second view, adding it as a subview for the first time only when the user presses the toolbar button, iOS does not resize the view to account for the toolbar in its parent view, and it underlaps the toolbar which messes up my Autolayout constraints. Also, when I don't add the subview in viewDidLoad, if I put the device in landscape orientation before switching to the second view, it loads with a portrait orientation frame.

**Bottom line:** When inserting a subview in viewDidLoad, iOS sizes it correctly and manages autorotation for it. When inserting it later, I need to detect orientation set the frame myself. (And for some reason when I do this, autorotation kicks in again).

What is going on?

Comment: try calling `setNeedsLayout` on the controller's view after adding the subview.

Answer (score 5):

In viewDidLoad, the view is not yet layout for the resolution and interface orientation, and view properties are as they were in the interface designer. So, if you had a portrait view, that is how the initial properties of the view are set when going into viewDidLoad. When you add your view there, you add it to the XIB view. Later, iOS performs layout on the view hierarchy and thus resizes your inserted view as needed. But when adding your view at a later point, the view hierarchy has already been layout, so it is expected that the new view you are adding is also layout correctly.

Best practice is to calculate the size you need using the size of the view you are inserting into. For example, half the width of the containing view, or third the bounds, etc. This way it is independent on the orientation the interface is in.

Comment: "Later, iOS performs layout on the view hierarchy and thus resizes your inserted view as needed." Is there any way to trigger this process when adding a view at a later point?

Comment: No, because at the point of adding your view, it has to be layout correctly for the interface orientation.

Comment: So how do you know when the autoresizing is complete?

Comment: In your view controller, implement `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Don't forget to call the super implementation. This will tell you when the view finished layout.